# Installed Nginx on Ubuntu Server 14.04, but can't create any files in html folder?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, permissions

I bought a server on DigitalOcean, and I'm trying to set up some pages using PHP and Nginx following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) they provide.

However I cannot create a file in `/usr/share/nginx/html` without running `sudo`. Even just `touch test.php` will not work, resulting in a "Permission denied" error.

How do I make it so I can create files for my website without requiring `sudo` every time? I feel like I'm doing something wrong despite following the DigitalOcean guide closely, and I don't want to go mucking around with permissions without knowing what I'm doing and compromise my site.

Comment: so what's the ownership of that folder, v.s. whatever account you're logged in as? That's what you have to fix.

Comment: @MarcB For someone who is quite new to servers could you explain that a little further? Perhaps a link?

Comment: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: @MarcB Okay, understood for the most part. When I `ls -l` the directory with the `html` folder in it I get: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  3 16:00 html`, and where I'm not the root user should I `chown` it to allow my user?

Comment: it'd have to be owned by whatever user your webserver is running under, AND have permission for your own account to get in. and this is getting out of programming territory into server configuration,w hich is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways to skin this cat...
I would avoid opening permission via relaxed chmod and use groups

What I would do is add your user to the group that owns the directory , or create a new directory under your user and add nginx to your users group to ensure nginx can read and or execute the files.

Example: if nginx is the owner of the folder and you wish to maintain the current directory setup/ownership add your user to the nginx user group

$: sudo gpasswd -a username nginx 
( username being the user that wants permission to the folder )

If you create a new directory under the user and wish nginx access to read and execute the files add nginx user to your users group

Edit: restart nginx afterwards